# Insert in mysql from php saves a date field as 00:00:00 instead of NULL

Tags: php, mysql, date, null

I receive via POST the following variables, sometimes it must be a date and sometimes it must be null (for example if that event has not happened yet)

```
$hora_entrada = $_POST['hora_entrada'];
$salida_comida = $_POST['salida_comida'];
$regreso_comida = $_POST['regreso_comida'];
$hora_salida = $_POST['hora_salida'];
```

so, I assign NULL into the variables if POST is empty:

```
if ($hora_entrada == '') {$hora_entrada = "NULL";}
if ($salida_comida == '') {$salida_comida = "NULL";}
if ($regreso_comida == '') {$regreso_comida = "NULL";}
if ($hora_salida == '') {$hora_salida = "NULL";}
```

now, I want to insert the values into a mysql table:

```
UPDATE  `nomina`.`registro_tiempo` SET  
`hora_entrada` =  '$hora_entrada',
`salida_comida` =  '$salida_comida',
`regreso_comida` =  '$regreso_comida',
`hora_salida` =  '$hora_salida',
WHERE  `registro_tiempo`.`id_tiempo` ='$id_tiempo';
") or die (mysql_error());
```

the problem is that when the variable is NULL the record says 00:00:00 and I want to keep it NULL

I tried to assign NULL in this two ways without success:

```
$variable = NULL;

$variable = "NULL";
```

NOTE: The MySql fields have the NULL value as Predetermined.

¿Do you know any other way to do this? I will apreciate your help

Comment: show `DESC 'registro_tiempo'` please.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the quotes around `'NULL'` are what's doing it. But you should *really*, *really*, **really** read up on SQL injection attacks!

Comment: A time column = "NULL" => '00:00:00'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is `'NULL'` and `NULL` are two different things to SQL.  You are inserting `'NULL'` (the literal string NULL) when you should be inserting `NULL` (The predetermined NULL value)

```
UPDATE  `nomina`.`registro_tiempo` SET  
`hora_entrada` =  'NULL',
`salida_comida` =  'NULL',
`regreso_comida` =  'NULL',
`hora_salida` =  'NULL',
WHERE  `registro_tiempo`.`id_tiempo` ='$id_tiempo';
") or die (mysql_error());
```

It should be

```
UPDATE  `nomina`.`registro_tiempo` SET  
`hora_entrada` =  NULL,
`salida_comida` =  NULL,
`regreso_comida` =  NULL,
`hora_salida` =  NULL,
WHERE  `registro_tiempo`.`id_tiempo` ='$id_tiempo';
") or die (mysql_error());
```

To do an easy fix is to put logic to wrap the contents with quotes if it isn't NULL:

```
<?php
$var = $var != "" ? "'" . $var . "'" : "NULL";
$sql = "INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ('$id', $var)";
?>
```

**And remember to escape your content (especially if it is provided by the user!)**  See http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

**EDIT:**

```
<?php
// If the variable is not null/empty, wrap quotes around it. Otherwise, store as NULL
$hora_entrada = $_POST['hora_entrada'] != "" ? "'" . $_POST['hora_entrada'] . "'" : "NULL";
$salida_comida = $_POST['salida_comida'] != "" ? "'" . $_POST['salida_comida'] . "'" : "NULL";
$regreso_comida = $_POST['regreso_comida'] != "" ? "'" . $_POST['regreso_comida'] . "'" : "NULL";
$hora_salida = $_POST['hora_salida'] != "" ? "'" . $_POST['hora_salida'] . "'" : "NULL";

// You should also mysqli_real_escape_string them
$hora_entrada = mysqli_real_escape_string($hora_entrada);
$salida_comida = mysqli_real_escape_string($salida_comida);
$regreso_comida = mysqli_real_escape_string($regreso_comida);
$hora_salida = mysqli_real_escape_string($hora_salida);

"UPDATE  `nomina`.`registro_tiempo` SET  
`hora_entrada` =  $hora_entrada,
`salida_comida` =  $salida_comida,
`regreso_comida` =  $regreso_comida,
`hora_salida` =  $hora_salida,
WHERE  `registro_tiempo`.`id_tiempo` ='$id_tiempo';
") or die (mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: yes, I understand. The problem is that I want to insert the value from a variable.
`salida_comida` =  '$variable', returns 00:00:00
`salida_comida` =  $variable, returns "You have an error in your SQL syntax; etc..."

Comment: Can you `echo` your whole SQL string and post it?

Comment: I've never heard before about mysqli_real_escape_string, I'm reading the manual right now. The answer looks very intresting. I will try.

Answer (score 1):

If your column is set to allow `NULL` values, when you want to insert `NULL`, it cannot be in quotes.

That is, your query looks like this right now:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (datecol) VALUES('NULL');
```

but it has to look like:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (datecol) VALUES(NULL);
```

You can use:

```
$variable = "NULL"; // for null values
// and
$variable = "'2012-07-01'"; // for actual date values
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use TIME column data type, documentation clearly states that when TIME object is invalid it defaults to 00:00:00.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time.html

You might want to add a boolean column "validDate" and set it to false when NULL date is set.

Answer (score 0):

```
$hora_entrada = "'".$_POST['hora_entrada']."'";
$salida_comida = "'".$_POST['salida_comida']."'";
$regreso_comida = "'".$_POST['regreso_comida']."'";
$hora_salida = "'".$_POST['hora_salida']."'";

if ($_POST['hora_entrada'] == '') {$hora_entrada = "NULL";}
if ($_POST['salida_comida'] == '') {$salida_comida = "NULL";}
if ($_POST['regreso_comida'] == '') {$regreso_comida = "NULL";}
if ($_POST['hora_salida'] == '') {$hora_salida = "NULL";}

"UPDATE  `nomina`.`registro_tiempo` SET  
`hora_entrada` =  $hora_entrada,
`salida_comida` =  $salida_comida,
`regreso_comida` =  $regreso_comida,
`hora_salida` =  $hora_salida,
WHERE  `registro_tiempo`.`id_tiempo` ='$id_tiempo';
") or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: To append string in php, you use `.` not `+`

Answer (score 0):

First check $_POST is set and then assign null

```
$hora_entrada = $_POST['hora_entrada'];    
if (isset($hora_entrada) && empty($hora_entrada)) {
    $hora_entrada = null;
}
```